# how to install deepfreeze after force defreeze

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, date-time, debug, deep-freeze

i installed deepfreeze on windows 10 pro.
i promptly forgot the password.
prehaps i should have done something else.
out of desparation is booted into the bios and set to clock to three months from now (i think we all know that deepfreeze boots thawed when it's expired).

i 'shift' restarted and booted windows in 'debug'.

i 'end'ed 'task' in task manager and deleted the fabronics folder.

i ran ccleaner and even deleted the regestry folder.

when i thought deepfreeze is gone for good i did what i need to do and downloaded deepfreeze again.

and this is what is got...

[Deep Freeze Standard must be disabled before any Install/Uninstall can proceed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLPsy.png)

can someone explain to me what is going on here?

there is no deep freeze in my tray.
no deep freeze in task manager.
truely, no where. there is no deep freeze.
i'm confused. how am i going to install deep freeze now?

Comment: How Deep Freeze works: *Deep Freeze uses patented technology to redirect information being written to the hard drive to an allocation table, leaving the original data intact.* Pretty sure you have an extra partition for Deep Freeze still active.

Comment: @Nastu Kage the thaw space is still there. i wasnt able to delete it. deepfreeze not freezing anyhting even after i restored the system clock. so it's something in the middle. not uninstalled and disabled all at the same time. what can i do, i can't delete the thaw space.

Comment: At this point: is it possible to reinstall windows in your situation?

Comment: @Natsu Kage i can reinstall windows. i can do anything. deepfreeze is dead. i just can't install deepfreeze because deepfreeze detects another deepfreeze installed.

Comment: Then you will need to clean format the hard drive to reinstall windows. Once the HDD is cleaned up, you can reinstall deepfreeze. Getting another disk, such as an SSD is a good idea too.

Comment: i'm looking all over how to delete thaw space. do you have an idea? i want to avoid reinstalling windows although it is an option.

Comment: Did you check for the presence of depfrez.sys as a file or inside config.sys ?

Comment: i dont know how to locate config.sys on windows 10 but i can say that depfreeze seems to be working because all changes to the system are getting erased at restart. again, i do not see the presense of deepfreeze anywhere. i can over clock the machine again to make changes but i want to remove deepfreeze not overclock every time i want to make changes.